# How to render a block in magento .phtml file?

Tags: magento

I am trying to render the magento contact form into a .phtml file, but I cannot find anything on Google to get the PHP code to do it.

I only know the code to use in magento's CMS system which is:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the XML block is placed correctly, in a phtml file you should be able to bring it out with:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('contactForm') ?>
```

Comment: I've added '<block name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"></block>' to my .xml for the page between '<reference name="content"></reference>', and i've added your code to the .phtml file. it doesn't seem to work, I took out the 'type="core/template"' since that made it render under my page rather than within a certain place on my page. i'm not sure which type to use.

Comment: What phtml file are you trying to echo it out on? This will determine where you put the block in the XML.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the contact form with in a `phtml` page then...

1. add the block to the xml you want for example I wanted to add a request form to the product view so, i went to catalog.xml at the `<reference name="content">` and add:

   ```
   <block type="core/template" 
          name="contactForm" 
          form_action="/contacts/index/post" 
          template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
   ```
2. just add the `getChildHtml`:

   getChildHtml('contactForm') ?>

So simple, I know, but took me 3 coffees like all easy things in magento...